# Unable to access newly created web site in IIS 7.5

Tags: iis-7.5, asp.net-mvc

```
Configuration: 32-bit Windows 7 development machine with IIS 7.5
```

I created a new web site in IIS to host only MVC sites called `MVCHOST`. The physical path to this website is set as `C:\inetpub\mvcroot`. I created a new v4.0 pool called `mvcpool` for this purpose.

I have given Modify rights to `IIS_WPG`, `IIS_IUSRS`, `ASPNET` accounts.

I created this web site with a host header "mvchost" and port 80, in the hopes of browsing MVC sites in the following way:

1. mvchost/mvcapp1
2. mvchost/mvcapp2

instead of

1. localhost/mvcapp1
2. localhost/mvcapp2

The only binding I set is the default one: `http:*:80:mvchost`. I have also copied the files `iisstart.htm`, `web.config`, `welcome.png` and folder `aspnet_client` from `wwwroot` over to `mvcroot`.

Now when I try to the browse this site from IIS manager, I get the following error:

```
This webpage is not available
```

If I leave out the host header and give some port, say 99, I can access this website at localhost:99.

What am I missing here? Why am I unable to access the web site at: `http://mvchost/`?

Comment: Don't you need a dns record for "mvchost"?

Comment: @AmiramKorach: I am not aware of this, thanks for pointing this out. I guess I would need to contact the network people for getting a dns record created.

Comment: You can also override it localy for testing http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/

Comment: I am generally aware of hosts file, but in this case I have no clue how to modify it so that http://mvchost/ can be accessible.

Comment: I added an entry `127.0.0.1    mvchost` as an entry at the bottom and now I am able to access `http://mvchost/`

Comment: Great. So it is definitely a dns issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to all these settings you need to define a dns entry in the dns server with the `mvchost` name

Comment: What additional help would this do, if I am already able to do it locally? Would it let other people in LAN access it as such?

Comment: Yes, but it depends on some other things like firewall settings.